# Appium get list items

Tags: list, scala, selenium, appium

I have Appium with Android device and I simply need get all items from list on screen. If I try

```
val x = driver.findElement(By.tagName("list"))
```

it gives me RemoteWebElement but Im not able to get its items or cast it to List or something like that.

Any idea how to get list of items?

Comment: Why aren't you using findElements(By.tagName("list"))?

Comment: Its same result, only get ArrayList with one object - that RemoteWebElement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this with:

```
val list = driver.findElement(By.tagName("list"))
val listItems = list.findElements(By.tagName("text"))
```

it gives me list of visible WebElements from list and I can navigate through them with simple:

```
listItems.get(5)
```